# Replace one matched value in a hash with another

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array of hashes:

```
arr = [
  {:key1=>"one", :key2=>"two", :key3=>"three"},
  {:key1=>"four", :key2=>"five", :key3=>"six"},
  {:key1=>"seven", :key2=>"eight", :key3=>"nine"}
]
```

and I would like to search through and replace the value of `:key1` with `"replaced"` if `:key` = `"one"`.

The resultant array would then read:

```
arr = [
  {:key1=>"replaced", ;key2=>"two", :key3=>"three"},
  {:key1=>"four", ;key2=>"five", :key3=>"six"},
  {:key1=>"seven", ;key2=>"eight", :key3=>"nine"}
]
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the following code to see if it solves your problem

```
arr.each { |item| item[:key1] = "replaced" if item[:key1] == "one" }
```

Comment: great thanks - there is a curly brace missing, but a REALLY helpful and speedy response thanks

Comment: ...five years later, that curly brace has been added.

Comment: Great thanks for adding that, I did not notice this until I got a notification for your comment lol

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [
  {:key1=>"one", :key2=>"two", :key3=>"three"},
  {:key1=>"four", :key2=>"five", :key3=>"six"},
  {:key1=>"seven", :key2=>"eight", :key3=>"nine"}
]

p arr.each {|x| x[:key1] = "replaced" if x.assoc(:key1).include? "one"}
```

or

```
p arr.each {|x| x[:key1] = "replaced" if x.values_at(:key1) == "one"}
```

*Output:*

```
[{:key1=>"replaced", :key2=>"two", :key3=>"three"}, {:key1=>"four", :key2=>"five", :key3=>"six"}, {:key1=>"seven", :key2=>"eight", :key3=>"nine"}]
```